# Mapster plugin jQuery

Tags: jquery, imagemapster

I need to set event "on click" on map area without declared area id. My map of country has 5 areas with id, like that:

```
<area shape="poly" name="Area 1" coords="343,183 etc" title="My area 1" id="1" href="#">
```

In JS I have function:

```
$('#my-map-div').mapster({
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    fillColor: "FFFFFF",
    stroke: false,
    onClick: function (e) { 
        alert('HERE IS MY ACTION');
 }
```

When I click on area with id, a see my alert.

What about rest of map, without declared area coords, area id etc? How to set event "on click" ? I need to get alert when someone click on map out of area.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may already have found an answer but, for anyone else wondering, you can just put the onclick calls on the areas, instead of in the mapster() function, eg:

```
<area shape="poly" coords="192, 187, 120, 108, 151, 85, 183, 70, 215, 61, 252, 57, 252, 164, 232, 166, 210, 174" href="#" onclick="alert('you clicked me');" />
```

and for the rest of the map, the default area can have an onclick in the same way:

```
<area shape="default" href="#" onclick="alert('dont click here, whatever you do');">
```